# Redirect Out of Stock Product to the related category - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

this quest is related to WordPress woo commerce.
Q: When a product gets Out-Of-Stock, the user get redirected automatically to the product's related category using the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straight forward, you can use `get_stock_quantity()` to retrieve the product stocks. [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) to retrieve the product categories, and [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) for the term url.

The following is untested, but should work.

```
<?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_product() ) {

        global $product;

        $product_id = $product->get_id();

        if ( $product->get_stock_quantity() < 1 ) {

            $terms =  get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
            
            if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

                $location = get_term_link( $terms[0]->slug );

                wp_safe_redirect( $location, 302 );

            };

        };

    };

} );
```

Comment: You're using `$post->ID` but `$post` is undefined in your code. `template_redirect` hook should be used for redirect and avoid the header already sent,  not the 'init'

Comment: Indeed. `$post->ID` was just a copy paste error. `template_redirect ` is indeed the right hook. Answering at 2 am is never a great idea

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add this code to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_out_of_stock_products' );

function redirect_out_of_stock_products() {
    // Check if it's a single product page
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post;
        // Check if the product is out of stock
        if ( ! $post || 'product' !== $post->post_type || ! $post->ID ) {
            return;
        }

        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

        if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            // Get the category IDs associated with the product
            $product_categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
            
            // Check if the product has any categories
            if ( ! empty( $product_categories ) ) {
                // Get the first category ID
                $category_id = $product_categories[0];
                
                // Get the category URL
                $category_url = get_term_link( $category_id, 'product_cat' );

                // Redirect to the category page
                wp_redirect( $category_url );
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```